# Addressing Compatibility Issues with Apache Commons FileUpload in Java 17: Transitioning from javax.servlet to jakarta.servlet

Tags: servlets, apache-commons-fileupload, jakarta-migration

`During the migration of our codebase from Java 11 to Java 17, we encountered compatibility issues with the Apache Commons FileUpload library (version 1.4). The problem arises because the library's methods, such as getItemIterator, rely on javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, which is incompatible with Java 17. In Java 17, the standard has moved to jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.

The specific method causing the issue is as follows:

public FileItemIterator getItemIterator(HttpServletRequest request) throws FileUploadException, IOException {
return super.getItemIterator(new ServletRequestContext(request));
}

`Given that Java 17 now uses jakarta.servlet, what would be the recommended approach to address this compatibility gap? Are there updated versions of the Apache Commons FileUpload library that support jakarta.servlet and are compatible with Java 17?

I tried to use the latest version of libary found in maven repository.https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.5

Getting the following compile time error ,Multiple markers at this line - The type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload - The method getItemIterator(HttpServletRequest) from the type ServletFileUpload refers to the missing type HttpServletRequest```

Comment: This is completely unrelated to Java 17. `jakarta.*` package is not at all part of Java SE.  This problem is just caused by migration to a newer servletcontainer (a newer Tomcat version probably). You just need to migrate code to use `HttpServletRequest#getPart()` which was introduced in 2009(!!) to replace Apache Commons FileUpload. See abovelinked duplicate to get started.